# Left-join Query with filter in right table for a view

Tags: sql, left-join

- I need a left join query for a view

  - I have two filters for this view with
    parameters for the left and the right table.
  - I need the null line from the right table.

This first query didn't work, but I can filter it from a view :

```
select * from histoStatut h
left join listStatut ls on h.idstatutid = ls.idstatutid or ls.idstatutid is null
where h.idRequestid = 32651 and ls.IdListeId = 9 ;
```

This second query works but the filter on the rigth table is not acceptable for a view:

```
select *
from (select * from HistoStatut)T1
left join 
  (select h.*,ls.IdListeId from HistoStatut h
     inner join ListStatut ls on h.IdStatutId = ls.IdStatutId and ls.IdListeId = 9
  ) T2 on T1.IdHistoStatut = T2.IdHistoStatut
where T1.IdRequestId = 32651
```

[Here, a sample on Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88eaab/12/0)

I need a solution where I can use the two filters on a view :

```
CREATE VIEW AS My_Left_Join as 
  select * 
  from histoStatut h
  left join listStatut ls 
  on h.idstatutid = ls.idstatutid;

Select * from My_Left_Join where IdListeId = 9 and IdRequestId = 32651
```

Expected result : [image]

Is there a solution for a view ?

Comment: You can skip the `ls.idstatutid is null` condition, not needed here.

Comment: What does "_the filter on the rigth table is not acceptable for a view_" mean?

Comment: @Remay, please show expected result of queries.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MSSQL. I complete my question with expected form and result. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`ls.idstatutid is null` makes no sense in a join condition.

You can put where conditions into the right table by applying them as join conditions:

```
select * 
from histoStatut h
left join listStatut ls 
on h.idstatutid = ls.idstatutid 
and ls.IdListeId = 9
where h.idRequestid = 32651  ;
```

Comment: I need the filter IdListeId in the where clause

Comment: @Remay If you put it in a where clause this becomes an inner join. Based on your sample results, you do not want an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the reasons why the condition with value is not allowed on the right table since the syntax using `IdListeId = 9` as part `LEFT JOIN` is completely valid in SQL Server. I'm not quite sure what is allowed in your view but this may help

```
SELECT *
FROM histoStatut h
LEFT JOIN 
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM listStatut 
   WHERE IdListeId = 9
) ls ON h.idstatutid = ls.idstatutid
WHERE h.idRequestid = 32651;
```

Another rewriting of your query using `RIGHT JOIN` may be

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM listStatut 
   WHERE IdListeId = 9
) ls
RIGHT JOIN histoStatut h ON h.idstatutid = ls.idstatutid
WHERE h.idRequestid = 32651;
```

Comment: That didn't work, the 'ls.IdListeId = 9' must be in the where clause for the view, but it's a nice simplification